# Restore in-app purchases

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin InAppBilling to do in-app purchases.

Is it possible to restore previous purchases? I have looked everywhere but can't find any information that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.

Xamarin allows you to wrap java jar files, and in this case you need google play store jar (this answer assumes you want to use google play store to do in-app billing from, rather than going on, say, amazons app store) and use the java api. This answer ([Cannot figure out how to restore transactions on in-app purchases in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768347/cannot-figure-out-how-to-restore-transactions-on-in-app-purchases-in-android?rq=1)) explains some of the Java code needed, it shouldn't be at all that difficult to write it in C# as the apis are the same.

One thing to keep in mind is that you may not be able to restore consumable/one-time purchases, such as in game currency.

Here is the official android guide on in game purchases: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Comment: How do I test it? In Xamarin you can only test with pre defined test products and they won't be saved as transactions. Do I have to upload it to google play just to test it?